# Unit test of a function containing promises is not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a controller that handles signing a user in. I'm getting an error and think it may have something to do with the code using promises but I'm not really sure at this point. Here's the controller.

```
angular.module('app').controller('SignIn', SignIn);

function SignIn ($scope, $state, auth) {

    $scope.credentials = {};

    // signin
    $scope.signIn = function () {
        auth.signIn($scope.credentials)
            .then(function () {
                $state.go('user.welcome');
            }, function (res) {
                $scope.signInError = res.statusText;
            });
    };
}
```

Here's the auth services.

```
angular.module('app').factory('auth', auth);

function auth (session, api) {
    return {
        signIn : function (credentials) {
            return api.signIn(credentials)
                .then(function (res) {
                    session.create(res.data.sessionId, res.data.userName);
                });
        },
        signout: function () {
            return session.destroy();
        },
        isAuthenticated: function () {
            return !!session.userName;
        }
    };
}
```

The api just returns $http promises.

```
signIn : function (credentials) {
    return $http.post(base + '/auth/credentials', credentials);
}
```

And session is just a factory to store the current session info as well as save it to the browser's cookies.

Here is my jasmine test

```
describe('SignIn', function () {

// setup ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // init app module
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    // inject Session service
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _auth_) {
        $rootScope             = _$rootScope_;
        $scope                 = $rootScope.$new();
        controller             = _$controller_("SignIn", {$scope: $scope});
        auth                   = _auth_;
    }));

    // setup spies
    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(auth, 'signIn');
    });

// tests ------------------------------------------------------------------

    // signin in
    it("should call auth.signIn with the user's credentials", function () {
        $scope.signIn();
        expect(auth.signIn).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

I'm just trying to test that auth.signIn is called when you call $scope.signIn(). The application itself it working but I am getting this error when trying to run this test.

```
SignIn should call auth.signIn with the user's credentials FAILED
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'auth.signIn($scope.credentials).then')
```

Although there is an expectation there, the error is happening when I call $scope.signIn(); If I log auth right before $scope.signIn(); is called I get this.

```
LOG: Object{signIn: function () { ... }, signout: function () { ... }, isAuthenticated: function () { ... }}
```

So I assume the DI is working as expected. I've looked at different ways of setting up spies but haven't figured out what is actually wrong yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but there are several issues around statusText in angular. Probably best to not count on that in your errback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are spying on `auth`'s `signIn` function. When you spy on it, it wont be your real function in the api any more. So you need to send a promise from the spy by using [.and.returnValue](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>and.returnValue).

So do:-

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _auth_, _$q_) {
    $rootScope             = _$rootScope_;
    $scope                 = $rootScope.$new();
    controller             = _$controller_("SignIn", {$scope: $scope});
    auth                   = _auth_;
    fakePromise = _$q_.when(); //get a fake promise
}));

beforeEach(function () {
  spyOn(auth, 'signIn').and.returnValue(fakePromise); //return fakepromise
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4gDw9?p=preview)**

and if you were to return some value fro signIn (or any other function's promise, just do)

```
  fakeAuthPromise = _$q_.when(somedata);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and made the error make sense. I did have to change '.and.returnValue(); to .andReturn(); That may be a jasmine version difference. What is $q.when() doing? Without passing it more data does that just return a generic promise?

Comment: Yes $q.when() returns a promise object which has then and other promise methods